# srtool-cli no rust-src error

Tags: releases, srtool

I'm attempting to debug a release error on our chain (for reference, our chain uses a gitlab-ci and not any provided GitHub Actions) that surfaced after upgrading to the latest Polkadot release. This issue can be reproduced locally using the polkadot-sdk:

```bash
cd polkadot-sdk
git checkout polkadot-v1.6.0
srtool build --app --root --package=rococo-runtime -r polkadot/runtime/rococo/
```

This will result in a failure:

```
--- stderr
  Cannot compile the WASM runtime: no standard library sources found!
  You can install them with `rustup component add rust-src` if you're using `rustup`.
```

Performing the exact same build process using `polkadot-v1.4.0` or prior is successful.

What am I doing wrong here?

Tried with:

```bash
{
  "name": "srtool",
  "version": "0.13.0",
  "rustc": "1.74.0",
  "subwasm": "v0.20.0",
  "tera": "0.2.4",
  "toml": "0.2.4"
}
```

And

```bash
srtool-cli 0.12.0
```

I have only found one workaround for this issue, which is to copy a `rust-toolchain.toml` file directly into `polkadot/runtime/rococo/`, which will force the toolchain update and install the `rust-src` component.

Answer (score 0):

encountered the same issue while upgrading dependencies to `polkadot-v1.6.0`. Fix was very simple and as suggested by the error log:

```bash
rustup component add rust-src
```

Comment: It didn't work for us because srtool (with the latest docker image) overrides the installed chain with its own, hence the workaround that I explained before.

It probably also depends on the project's architecture, as I have noticed that simple projects with only one runtime don't suffer from this problem."

Comment: hmm, makes sense. for me, the issue was raised in CI and adding this line to toolchain installation command fixed it. I am also working with two runtimes, so probably it's more `srtool` specific

Comment: The issue was also raised in your GitLab CI, likely from an incomplete tool chain installation in the Docker image. In fact, with polkadot-v1.7.1, other components are also missing.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed by this. Otherwise it should be possible https://github.com/paritytech/srtool/pull/81.

As workaround you can try the command here for building the runtimes, we use it in Polkadot: https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/releases/tag/v1.1.3